# Can we pass callback function in object prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to pass a callback function in a prop of type object. I have created a custom component for data table in that component I am passing `columns, data` and `actions` as props.

actions props is an array of objects with handler callback function linked to each element.

Here is my Data table component code

```
const DataTable = ({ columns, data, actions }) => {
return <>
<TableContainer>
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>#</TableCell>
                {
                    columns.map((item) => {
                        return (<TableCell key={item.key}>{item.label}</TableCell>);
                    })
                }
                {
                  actions && <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
                }
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data.map((row, index) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row.id}
                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
              >
                <TableCell>
                  {index + 1}
                </TableCell>
                {
                    columns.map(item => {
                        return (<TableCell key={item.key}>{row[item.key] ? row[item.key] : ''}</TableCell>);
                    })
                }
                <TableCell>
                    {
                      actions.map((element) => {
                        return (<React.Fragment key={element.label}><span onClick={(row) => {element.handler(row.id)}}>{element.icon}</span></React.Fragment>)
                      })
                    }
                  </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <Pagination count={1} />
      </TableContainer>
</>
}

export default DataTable;
```

and here is code of using that data table

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const columns = [
  {
    key: "provider",
    label: "Provider",
  },
  {
    key: "phone_number",
    label: "Phone Number",
  },
  {
    key: "status",
    label: "Status",
  },
];

const actions = [
  {
    icon: <VisibilityIcon sx={{ color: '#1976d2', cursor: 'pointer' }} />,
    label: 'View',
    handler: ''
  },
  {
    icon: <DeleteIcon sx={{ color: '#1976d2', marginLeft: '4px', cursor: 'pointer' }} />,
    label: 'Delete',
    handler: deleteHandler
  }
];

// Fetching data from api

const deleteHandler = async (id) => {
  // Calling delete api
}

return <>
  <Card>
    <CardContent>
      <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} actions={actions} />
    </CardContent>
  </Card></>;
```

Now on clicking on any action button I am getting this error

```
TypeError: element.handler is not a function
```

Is there any specific way using which i can pass these callback function inside prop object.

Comment: You're not consistenty assigning a function to the `handler` property. ie `handler: ''` where you're assigning an empty string. You'll need to provide a noop (`handler: () => {}`) or check that `element.handler` is a function before trying to call it.

Comment: Thanks @pilchard this worked for unassigned handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the `element.handelr` is a function or not

```
// in your child component

const actionFn = (id, handler) => {
 if (typeof handler !== 'function' ) {
   return;
 }
 handler(row.id);
}

// JSX
<TableCell>
    {
       actions.map((element) => {
          return <React.Fragment key={element.label}>
           <span onClick={(row) => {actionFn(row.id, element.handler)}}>{element.icon}</span>
         </React.Fragment>
       })
    }
</TableCell>
```

Also move `const deleteHandler` above `const actions`

Comment: Thanks moving deleteHandler above actions array worked.